# CSS: allign img relative to div

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm relatively new to HTML and CSS and I'm trying to format a webpage.
I want to align four images to an `input div`. You can see the page [here](http://andrewbreckenridge.tumblr.com/), the four social media icons. I want them to be one after another in one row, aligned with the search bar above it. So like the center of the left part of the webpage?

Here's the HTML for the 4 images:

```
<div class="social-icons group"> 
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/asbreckenridge" title="" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/gray/facebook-24.jpg"></a>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/{text:Twitter Username}" title="" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/gray/twitter-24.jpg"></a>
    <a href="https://github.com/AndrewSB" title="" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/gray/github-6-24.jpg"></a>
    <a href="mailto:asbreckenridge@me.com?Subject=Contact%From%Blog"><img src="http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/gray/new-post-16.jpg"></a>
</div>`
```

and the CSS

```
body header .social-icons{font-size:20px;float:center;list-style:none;display:block;margin:0 5px 15px;width:24px;}
body header .social-icons a {color:#4f555b;display:block;opacity:0.8;text-decoration:none}
```

Comment: please make a JSFiddle

Comment: I'll make one and then edit it into the question. Couple minutes

Comment: Make a comment so I get the notification.

Comment: Do you want them aligned *under* the input element? Or aligned inline with the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want the following:

The element `.social-icons` is no longer floated, and the width was changed to `100%` to allow horizontal space for the children elements. The child `a` elements were changed from `display:block` to `display:inline-block`.

```
body header .social-icons {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

body header .social-icons a {
    color: #4f555b;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting them up as a ul with the text aligned center:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kiaaanabal/sSXDC/

```
ul.social-media li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can also set the width of both the input and the ul to be the same so they match up. Hope this helps!